# Find the correct integers

Tags: integers

What $3$ integers have a sum of $1$ and a product of $36$

Integers can be negative. I've tried but can't get it. Please help

Comment: $-2, -3, 6 {}{}{}{}{}{}{}$ is one such triplet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pretty quickly list out the combinations of 3 positive numbers whose product is 36.  It appears clear that two of the numbers will need to be negative, so find the set where the biggest number is 1 more than the sum of the smallest 2 numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Following turkeyhundt's method, we have (with triples arranged in non-decreasing order) the following:

$$1,1,36 \qquad 1,2,18\qquad 1,3,12\qquad 1,4,9$$

$$1,6,6\qquad \,\,2,2,9\qquad \,\,2,3,6\qquad\,\, 3,3,4$$

By trial and error, the only triples that will satisfy your requirements are the $6$ permutations of the one amWhy found: $$(-2,-3,6)\qquad (-2,6,-3)\qquad (6,-2,-3)$$

$$(-3,-2,6) \qquad (-3,6,-2)\qquad (6,-3,-2)$$

The only other unsigned triple that needed any consideration was $1,6,6$ ...